# How to generate a model in sencha?

Tags: extjs

So I was following a tutorial and this is how they tell me to generate the model:

```
sencha generate model -name Setting -fields id,city, country, units, geo:boolean
```

Then I realized that this is an old sencha command, So I found the folowwing

```
sencha generate model Setting id,city,country,units,geo:boolean
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Unexpected Argument: "city"
```

Then I checked the documentation and I came up with this command:

```
sencha generate model -n=Setting -f=id,city,country,units,geo:boolean
```

but now I get the following error:

```
Unexpected Argument: "units"
```

Can anyone guide on what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

So finally after try and try and try I finally found how to generate the model

```
sencha generate model Setting "id,city,country,units,geo:boolean"
```